# Paginate Tag Page

Tags: templating

I'm looking to paginate my `tag` page, but unfortuntately it throws a fairly strange error. Remove the pagination -> the page works perfectly? Bit confused, the only thing I think it may be is that it's only returning 1 result so errors?

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.title(tag).first() %}

{% set users = craft.users.group('influencer').relatedTo(tag).order('userTotalFollowers asc').all() %}

{% if users|length %}

{% paginate users as pageInfo, pageUsers %}
{% for user in users %}
  {{ user.username }}
{% endfor %}


<div class="row justify-content-between">
  <div class="col text-left">
    {% if pageInfo.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">← Previous</a>{% endif %}
  </div>
  <div class="col text-right">
    {% if pageInfo.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.nextUrl }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Next →</a>{% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

> Argument 1 passed to craft\helpers\Template::paginateCriteria() must
>   implement interface yii\db\QueryInterface, array given, called in
>   /app/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/ef/efb8567b56752c2a98d031bc1d51461f73acc6fdd1f2c8872e44feb2af18359c.php
>   on line 133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `all()` function at the end of your users-definition you get an array of all users.

The pagination expects a QueryInterface. This is logical: With pagination you *do not want* to load *all* users, only the ones listed on the page.

In addition, to paginate, you have to `limit()` your query to a number of entries.

Therefore: `{% set users = craft.users.group('influencer').relatedTo(tag).order('userTotalFollowers asc').limit(10) %}` should probably work.

You can find more information and an example in the [documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/paginate.html).

I hope this helps and solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying the loop to the following: {% for user in pageUsers %}

Comment: Hmm, changed it to this, unfortunately, it still error's. I've added the error.

Comment: You might still want to change the for loop for pagination to work properly. See here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/paginate.html

Answer (score -2):

All you need to do is add a limit in your user query. This might help you.